# how to setup mock object for dynamic linq

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq, repository-pattern

A service is calling a repository function "GetManyIncluded" which has a signature like mentioned below

```
     IQueryable<T> GetManyIncluded(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] children);
```

and in a test method i am setting it up like mentioned below

```
            mockedWrapper.Setup(x => x.DomainObject.GetManyIncluded(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DomainObject, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DomainObject, object>>[]>())).Returns<Expression<Func<DomainObject, bool>>>(expr => listOFObjects.Where(expr.Compile()).ToList().AsQueryable());
```

this gives me parameter count mismatch exception in the service.

please help.

Comment: i got it working 

            mockedWrapper
                .Setup(x => x.PatientPayer.GetManyIncluded(
                    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<PatientPayer, bool>>>(), 
                    It.IsAny<Expression<Func<PatientPayer, object>>[]>()))
                .Returns((Expression<Func<PatientPayer, bool>> expr, Expression<Func<PatientPayer,object>>[] includeProperties) => 
                    appliedPatientPayers.Where(expr.Compile()).ToList().AsQueryable());

Comment: You should in fact post your solution as an answer (below), not just a comment. If you do not, I will write it as an answer.

Comment: for some reason i cannot do this. my account is blocked for answering. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproducing the solution the asker found themselves.

The problem occurs when you use one of the overloads of `Returns` which takes in a `Func` delegate. That `Func` must *either* take zero parameters (i.e. a `Func<TResult>` where `TResult` is known at compile-time to be `IQueryable<DomainObject>` in your case) *or* take the exact list of parameter that matches the method you setup (`Func<T1, T2, T3, ..., Tn, TResult>` where the *n* `T` match the parameter list of the mocked method exactly).

You tried to use a subset of the parameters from the mocked method, but that is not allowed (will execute the `Setup` without error, but will fail with parameter count mismatch exception when the method is invoked on the mock object).

The solution is therefore:

```
  mockedWrapper
    .Setup(x => x.DomainObject.GetManyIncluded(
      It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DomainObject, bool>>>(),
      It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DomainObject, object>>[]>()
      ))
    .Returns(
          (
          Expression<Func<DomainObject, bool>> where,
          Expression<Func<DomainObject, object>>[] children
          )
            => listOFObjects.Where(where.Compile()).ToList().AsQueryable()
      );
```